# vue reload application contacts

Tags: javascript, vue.js, reload

Good day,

I have a problem with Vue.Js.

When I create a new row in the database.
I will use Vue.use (conctactApp) but the table will not load.

I need to press CTRL + F5 to refresh the catch. And then the table reloads with the new data.

When I tested Vue.js on localhost there was no problem.

```
<tbody ref="contactTable"  v-for="user in users" id="" >
            <tr>
                <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ user.telefon }}</td>
                <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
                <td>{{ user.poznamka }}</td>
                <td v-on:click="editContact" :contact-poznamka="user.poznamka" :contact-email="user.email" :contact-telefon="user.telefon" :contact-name="user.name" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editcontact" ><i class="icofont-ui-edit"></i></td>
            </tr>

          </tbody>
```

---

```
var conctactApp = new Vue({

el:"#contactList",
data () {
    return {
      users: []
    }
  },
mounted () {
    console.log("Contact App Run")
    axios
      .get('action.php?action=load_conctacts')
      .then(response => (this.users = response.data))
},
methods: {
   reloadContacts(){
     Vue.use(conctactApp);
    },
  createContact(){
    let err = false;
    this.$refs.ecb.value = "Create";
    SetAttrById("ecb","send-type","create");
  },
  editContact: function(e){
      this.$refs.cContactName.value = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('contact-name');
      this.$refs.cContactEmail.value = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('contact-email');
      this.$refs.cContactTelefon.value = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('contact-telefon');
      this.$refs.cContactPoznamka.value = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('contact-poznamka');
      this.$refs.ecb.value = "Save";
      SetAttrById("ecb","send-type","edit");
  },
  saveContact:() => {
    var contactData = {
        name:GetInputValueById("cContactName"),
        telefon:GetInputValueById("cContactTelefon"),
        email:GetInputValueById("cContactEmail"),
        poznamka:GetInputValueById("cContactPoznamka"),
    }
    console.log(contactData);
    if(GetAttrById("ecb","send-type") == "create"){
       

        
        axios.post("api.php",{
            action:"autoinsert",
            autotable:"contacts",    
            data: contactData,
        }).then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            Vue.use(conctactApp);
        });

        
        
       
          
    }else if(GetAttrById("ecb","send-type") == "edit"){
        alert("edit");
    }
  }
}
```

})

I need each time i post new contact to db.
My table refresh and i not must press CTRL + F5
I m try forceupdate and not work too

Thanks for all help

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to reload the application after adding a contact.  After adding a contact, you could either add the new contact (user) to the 'users' data array, or just reload the data.

```
methods: {
  getContacts() {
    axios.get('action.php?action=load_contacts')
      .then(response => (this.users = response.data))
  },
  saveContact() {
    // other code
    if (GetAttrById("ecb", "send-type") == "create") {
      axios.post("api.php", {
        action: "autoinsert",
        autotable: "contacts",
        data: contactData,
      })
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response);

          // Reload contacts here
          this.getContacts();
        });
    }
    // other code
  }
},
mounted() {
  this.getContacts();
}
```